# concat prefix for every value in yaml array

Tags: symfony, yaml

Is there a way to concat a prefix for every value in an array? I want to avoid duplication in my configuration.

*in service.yaml*

```
cities:
- amsterdam
- brussels
- chicago
```

*wanted output in packages/city-package.yaml*

```
city_map:
- city_amsterdam
- city_brussels
- city_chicago

city_map: %cities% << concat 'city_'$value <----- something like this
```

Comment: I don't think so. You could perform that step somewhere in your logic though. Have `city_map: %cities%` then append `city_` wherever needed..

Comment: You can use lots of tools to achieve this. [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is viable if you know how to handle it, or you could write a small Python script that does it; most other scripting languages are viable too. There are too many possible answers, please be more specific with the tool you want to use.